# Django and tests in docfiles

Tags: python, django, testing, doctest

I'm having a small problem with my test suite with Django.

I'm working on a Python package that can run in both Django and Plone (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jquery.pyproxy).
All the tests are written as doctests, either in the Python code or in separate docfiles (for example the README.txt).

I can have those tests running fine but Django just do not count them:

```
[vincent ~/buildouts/tests/django_pyproxy]> bin/django test pyproxy
...
Creating test database for alias 'default'...

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

But if I had some failing test, it will appear correctly:

```
[vincent ~/buildouts/tests/django_pyproxy]> bin/django test pyproxy
...
Failed example:
    1+1
Expected nothing
Got:
    2
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of  44 in README.rst
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
Creating test database for alias 'default'...

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

This is how my test suite is declared right now:

```
import os
import doctest
from unittest import TestSuite

from jquery.pyproxy import base, utils

OPTIONFLAGS = (doctest.ELLIPSIS |
           doctest.NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE)

__test__ = {
    'base': doctest.testmod(
        m=base,
        optionflags=OPTIONFLAGS),

    'utils': doctest.testmod(
        m=utils,
        optionflags=OPTIONFLAGS),

    'readme': doctest.testfile(
        "../../../README.rst",
        optionflags=OPTIONFLAGS),

    'django': doctest.testfile(
        "django.txt",
        optionflags=OPTIONFLAGS),

    }
```

I guess I'm doing something wrong when declaring the test suite but I don't have a clue what it is exactly.

Thanks for your help,
Vincent

Comment: Do not put "I finally solved ..." in the question.  Remove this.  Create an answer.  If you solved it, you must post your solution as an answer.  It's much, much better to post answers as answers instead of continuations of the question.

Comment: That's what I tried first but I can not answer my own question until a few hours. I'll update this when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem with the `suite()` method:

```
import os
import doctest
from django.utils import unittest

from jquery.pyproxy import base, utils

OPTIONFLAGS = (doctest.ELLIPSIS |
               doctest.NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE)

testmods = {'base': base,
            'utils': utils}
testfiles = {'readme': '../../../README.rst',
             'django': 'django.txt'}

def suite():
    return unittest.TestSuite(
        [doctest.DocTestSuite(mod, optionflags = OPTIONFLAGS)
         for mod in testmods.values()] + \
        [doctest.DocFileSuite(f, optionflags = OPTIONFLAGS)
         for f in testfiles.values()])
```

Apparently the problem when calling `doctest.testfile` or `doctest.testmod` is that the tests are directly ran.
Using `DocTestSuite`/`DocFileSuite` builds the list and then the test runner runs them.